# Changing node connections to be straight?

Tags: node-editor

As is typical in this kind of thing I have a node tree filled with tangled curvy node connections going every which way. Even using reroutes it is somewhat difficult to read.

I've seen a number of people who have the node connections appear far more like a straight line than a bezier curve...how would I replicate this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the *User Preferences > Themes > Node Editor > Noodle Curving*

[image]

Comment: Just curious—is it possible to change this on a by-material basis? I generally enjoy the curved lines, they're just distracting in a complicated material.

Comment: It's a theme option, so I don't see how